# JSP path error on servlet redirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm new in java web development. When I use redirect from servlet to JSP the pictures and CSS files doesn't load. Without the servlet it's working well but when I want use servlet it's not working. The CSS file is in the same folder with the JSP one. Please can you help me how should I set the href attribute of the link tag ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
```

the servlet has only 1 command:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a runnable example, or at the very least some code and a detailed error description?

Comment: Can you please explain in brief with code?

Comment: I've always used, something like.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/desing.css"/>" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say to use redirect but you're using forwarding. Anyway, if the resources (CSS, JS, etc) files are not in the same path of your JSP, then you should append the request context for each of these. Here are two ways:

- Using Expression Language only:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${request.contextPath}/style.css">
  ```
- Using [JSTL `<c:url>`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/url.html) tag:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/style.css'/>">
  ```

---

From your comment:

> The problem was I cant use servlet urlPatterns = {"/"} with this pattern

You **can** have a servlet with url pattern `"/"`. It means that your servlet will handle **every single request** in your application, note that requests to the resources (CSS, JS, images, etc) are GET requests (you can easily verify this by opening a browser like Firefox with Firebug or Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and check for the network tab to see all the requests done to the server) so your servlet will handle them as well. This will be so painful to handle manually using a single servlet unless you want to implement [Front Controller Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) by yourself (IMO you should not try to do it unless **you really know** what you're doing).

A better recommendation would be to use an exact url pattern for your servlets, in order to avoid such problems.

Comment: Using JSTL is necessarily to append "<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>" at the top of the jsp file.

Comment: @hradecek yes, but that's something you should know if working with JSTL, which is outside this question's scope.

Comment: The problem was I cant use servlet urlPatterns = {"/"} with this pattern

Comment: I have to use index.jsp and not servlet with urlPatterns = {"/"}. So JSp file have to be loaded fisrt on the index page :)

Comment: Realy thanks for your help :) and sorry if i'm bit annoying :(

Comment: @user3546003 you're welcome. And you weren't annoying, the comment helped to have a better understanding of the problem and how to solve it.